# Sliding from one UIImage in an UIImageView to another while dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsmutablearray

Right now I have an NSMutableArray that contains image objects and I have UISwipeGestureRecognizer object that when called or swiped gives me the next image in my array. However, I would like to slide and be able to drag from the current image in my array to the next image in my array. I would like this to function like a Snapchat camera goes from one view to another on drag or such as tinder.

Comment: Why not `UICollectionView`?

Comment: So, what part of the code you've undoubtedly written so far do you not understand?

Comment: @nhgrif that's what I ended up doing is using a collectionView and setting the scroll to horizontal! Works like a beauty. Thanks all! I believe that was my first question here! More to come.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using a `UICollectionView`.